# Count the number of times a tag appears in influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I have an influxdb database called 'cars' that counts the cars that pass by my building.  One tag for this is called 'make', where make = {ford, toyota...}.  I'd like to count the number of times each car has passed by my building, by counting the number of entries with each tag.

Is this possible in InfluxDB?

Edit:

This does *not* work:

```
> select count(make) from my_series where time > now()-10d group by make;
name: my_series
tags: make=
time                count
----                -----
1524058438416676920 764724
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query like this will give you number of entries per make for the last hour:

```
SELECT COUNT(somefield) FROM cars WHERE time > now() - 1h GROUP BY make
```

Comment: Query does work and tells you that 764724 entries fopund for make=''. Looks like unset values for tag. Do you actually have non-empty values for `make` tag in data? Check with ` show tag values from cars with key = make` . Also try `select count(*) .... group by make;`